Conditional types with an inherited class in a generic function
I'm not sure how, given the following class structure and function:
class ClassA<T> {}

class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<T> {}

class ClassC<T> extends ClassA<T> {}

function doSomething<T> (classInstance: ClassA<T>) {

}

I can change the function by adding an optional argument (not breaking API) that is not accepted if the first argument is an instance of the ClassC class, but is accepted if the first argument is ClassA or ClassB instance:
class ClassA<T> {}

class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<T> {}

class ClassC<T> extends ClassA<T> {}

function doSomething<T> (classInstance: ClassA<T>, someValue?: T) {

}

doSomething<string>(new ClassA<string>); // should be allowed
doSomething<string>(new ClassA<string>, "abcd"); // should be allowed
doSomething<string>(new ClassB<string>, "abcd"); // should be allowed
doSomething<string>(new ClassB<string>); // should be allowed

doSomething<string>(new ClassC<string>); // should be allowed
doSomething<string>(new ClassC<string>, "abcd"); // should NOT be allowed

I tried tackling this with conditional types in a way similar to this:
type ValueType<T extends ClassA<any>, K> = T extends ClassC<any> ? never : K;

function doSomething<T> (
    classInstance: ClassA<T>,
    someValue?: ValueType<typeof classInstance, T> )
    {
}

But it does not work like I expected it to and does not solve my problem.

Please [edit] the code here to not have empty classes or unused generic type parameters. Presumably your actual code isn't empty like this, and it makes for very poor examples to remove all structural differences, since it makes things surprisingly identical. Your ClassA<number> is identical to ClassB<string> is identical to just {}.

In typescript, all empty classes have essentially the same type. You'll need to distinguish ClassC, perhaps by adding unique properties or methods:
class ClassC<T> extends ClassA<T> {
  #isC: true = true
  // ...
}

Then a possible solution is to add a conditional optional argument:
function doSomething<T, C extends ClassA<T>> (
  classInstance: C,
  ...[someValue]: C extends ClassC<T> ? [] : [someValue?: T]
) {
  // ...
}

Results in:
doSomething(new ClassA<string>); // ok
doSomething(new ClassA<string>, "abcd"); // ok
doSomething(new ClassB<string>, "abcd"); // ok
doSomething(new ClassB<string>); // ok
doSomething(new ClassC<string>); // ok
doSomething(new ClassC<string>, "abcd"); // error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2


It's clear that you want to match the type of the optional argument to the generic parameter of a class.
But it's not clear whether the function or the class should the type be inferred from.
I suggest the following - the class' generic parameter's type determines which type of the optional argument to pass:
Playground
class ClassA<T> {}

class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<T> {}

class ClassC<T> extends ClassA<T> {
    isC = true
}

function doSomething<C extends ClassC<unknown> | ClassB<unknown> | ClassA<unknown>> (
    classInstance: C, 
    ...args:[...C extends ClassC<any> ? [] : [someValue?: C extends ClassA<infer A> | ClassB<infer A> ? A : never]]
) {

}

doSomething(new ClassA<string>, 200); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
doSomething(new ClassA<string>); // should be allowed
doSomething(new ClassA<string>, "abcd"); // should be allowed
doSomething(new ClassB<string>, "abcd"); // should be allowed
doSomething(new ClassB<string>); // should be allowed

doSomething(new ClassC<string>); // should be allowed
doSomething(new ClassC<string>, "abcd"); // should NOT be allowed



